# Named Pipes IPC

Tags: perl, pipe, named-pipes

I am trying to create a pipe to use between two processes to send information. The two process are not related and implementation with signals has a problem where if the process that recieves the signal is doing a sys command it intreprets the signal as an intrupt. 
I am new to perl so any help trying to have two processes use pipes would be really great!!

Comment: More info would be great too. Are you on Windows or Linux for a start?

Answer (score 2):

The perl man page [perlipc](http://perl.active-venture.com/pod/perlipc-pipes.html) talks a bit about using named pipes.

Comment: Also look at http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html#Pipe-Opens for unnamed pipes (like the "|" operator in the shell).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention any specifics as to your project, so this may be completely off of what you are trying to achieve but have you considered implementing sockets as your IPC mechanism?  Again, I understand this may not make sense in the context of your particular project but it may allow you to create a process with the ability to communicate across a network instead of just one machine.